# Visible items of ListView

Tags: listview, javafx

Is there a way to get the visible items of a `ListView` in `JavaFX`?  I want to determine the first visible item displayed by a `ListView` in my `JavaFX` application.

The following code [found here](http://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/visible-rows-in-a-control.41719/) does not work for me (only for a `TableView`):

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public void getFirstAndLast(ListView<?> t) {
    try {
        ListViewSkin<?> ts = (ListViewSkin<?>) t.getSkin();
        VirtualFlow<?> vf = (VirtualFlow<?>) ts.getChildren().get(0);
        first = vf.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
        last = vf.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex();
    }catch (Exception ex) {}
}

public int getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public int getLast() {
    return last;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `onScrollTo`? Does that give you the information you need?

Comment: `onScrollTo` scroll to a specific index, what is not related to my question... I want to determine the index of the first visible item.

Comment: There's no way to do this (without some pretty ugly hacks, at least). Why do you need this (perhaps there is a different solution to what you are actually trying to achieve)?

Comment: I have to synchronise a horizontal and vertical `ListView`, but not item-to-item. It has to be binded by a time value of the items. To synchronize it correctly i need to get the first item...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @James_D explained, there isn't a nice out of the box solution but only hacks would work. I adapted a solution which i found on the web like the following.

```
[...]
private int first = 0;
private int last  = 0;

public void getFirstAndLast(ListView<?> t) {
    try {
        ListViewSkin<?> ts = (ListViewSkin<?>) t.getSkin();
        VirtualFlow<?> vf = (VirtualFlow<?>) ts.getChildren().get(0);
        first = vf.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
        last = vf.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex();
        logger.debug("##### Scrolling first {} last {}", first, last);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.debug("##### Scrolling: Exception " + ex);
    }
}

public int getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public int getLast() {
    return last;
}
[...]
```

Example output:

> 13:56:38.652 [X Application Thread] DEBUG getFirstAndLast     -
>   Scrolling #### first 11 last 20 13:56:48.503 [X Application Thread]
>   DEBUG getFirstAndLast     - Scrolling #### first 9 last 17
>   13:57:08.491 [X Application Thread] DEBUG getFirstAndLast     -
>   Scrolling #### first 7 last 15 13:57:18.371 [X Application Thread]
>   DEBUG getFirstAndLast     - Scrolling #### first 3 last 15